# Creating sub-web projects in Visual Studio 2013/15

Tags: asp.net, razor, visual-studio-2015, sitecore, sitecore7.2

We have a situation where we use Sitecore/.Net for our web portfolio.

Multiple teams are working on different sub web-projects.

Currently we are in a situation where we on build, copy all the cshtml and binaries to an out-of-solution folder - and from there do our explorative testing of the developed features.

This process is very slow and does not directly facilitate debugging : On every build we are doing copying in a post-build step. If we want to debug, we need to wait for the post-build xcopy and then manually attach a debugger to the IIS.

I would like to change this situation to a better solution structure, were we are able to debug directly using F5 - and do not rely on post-build copy deployment.

I have found this old article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307467

and this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2006/07/01/652986.aspx

And my question is: Do anyone have experience in creating a sub-web-project structure that works with F5 debugging in more modern version of Visual Studio, using Razor and Asp.Net 4.5?